# Why jQuery not working in Ajax loaded content?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to insert the div after every X number of widget-box inside:

> #activity-filterable-list .grid .grid

This content is BuddyPress activity and it loads in Ajax I believe, so jQuery fires up faster than the content loaded on the page finds nothing, and does nothing.

Jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#activity-filterable-list .grid .grid').children(':eq(2)').after('<button>button</button>');
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="activity-filterable-list" class="grid-column">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="widget-box no-padding animate-slide-down ">Box</div>
      <div class="widget-box no-padding animate-slide-down ">Box</div>
      <div class="widget-box no-padding animate-slide-down ">Box</div>
      <div class="widget-box no-padding animate-slide-down ">Box</div>
      <div class="widget-box no-padding animate-slide-down ">Box</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a word around?

Comment: `activity-filterable-list .grid .grid` you used same class twice `.grid` . While in your HTML you have `id='grid'`. change it to `class="grid"`

Comment: Sorry, it is mistake I did while creating example. In real it is class.
Edited the question.

Comment: You need to listen for the ajax result event.   How your content is loaded is the relevant part here.

Comment: If you have no idea when you receive the data, this is helpful: https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sm5aqzkg/ .... Note: you need to apply this code when BuddyPress activity loads the above HTML through Ajax.

Reference : https://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/ OR https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jquery-ajaxsuccess-method/

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
function waitFor(selector, callback) {
  if ($(selector).length) {
    callback();
  }
  else {
    // repeat wait
    setTimeout(function () {
      waitFor(selector, callback);
    }, 100);
  }
}

waitFor('#activity-filterable-list', function() {
  //.. do whatever you want
});
```